# How to find FFMPEG file path in godaddy vps server?

Tags: php, wordpress, ffmpeg, video-processing, vps

I am currently working on a Video sharing website. I am looking to automatically generate thumbnails for the videos that are uploaded. The godaddy support team helped in installing the ffmpeg library in VPS server. But when i try to upload the videos, i get the below error message

sh: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: No such file or directory

There are certain ways mentioned to find out the ffmpeg path but i am unable to proceed as i do not have much idea about SSH. Can you help me finding the easiest way to get the correct ffmpeg filepath in my server?

Comment: add more details to your questions. The question does not have clarity at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH into your vps and run the which command

ie: which ffmpeg